# Merge 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframe

for ex:

df1:

```
seq_id1     seq_id2
seq1_A      seq2_B
seq2_A      seq3_B
seq4_A      seq9_B
seq9_A      seq9_B
etc
```

and another dataframe such

df2:

```
sequences
seq2_A
seq9_A
```

and keep only in the first dataframe, the row where the ID in the dataframe is present, here it would be:

newdataframe merged:

```
seq_id1     seq_id2
seq2_A      seq3_B
seq9_A      seq9_B
```

Thanks for your help :)

here. are the dataframe=
First one with only 60 rows  : [df1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RTTsUZKDPQAKnQ3WpcRJPNv6kzvp94nH/view?usp=sharing)
second one with with all seq ID: [df2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yEwoV84T6Rpqb_NdFKldgQxYVbJ6a_h3/view?usp=sharing)
Here the columns `["#qseqid'"]` in the first df has to match with the restricted df2 in the column `["seq2_id"]`

Comment: Do you need check both columns in `df1` ?

Comment: I need to check only column ["#qseqid'"] and ["seq2_id"] in my data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need for match column `seq_id1` with `df2['sequences']` use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1[df1['seq_id1'].isin(df2['sequences'])]
```

Or:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='seq_id1', right_on='sequences')
```

If need match both columns of `df1`:

```
df1[df1.isin(df2['sequences']).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Hi, it is weird because I have in my first file 60 rows, then I should get get 60 row also in the newdataframe because all data are present in both but with more in the fasta file. I wrote a data link of my two data if you want to test the script on it?

Comment: @Benjamin - i test it by `df1 = pd.read_csv('Best_blast_candidate_hit_0042.csv')
print (df1.head())` and `df2 = pd.read_csv('Dataframe_HGT_candidates_filtered.csv', sep='\t')` and `a = df1[df1['#qseqid'].isin(df2['seq2_id'])]`

Comment: and get only 39 rows, `print (len(a))`

Comment: It is weird because the file with 60 seq is a filtred one of the file with 125 seq, do you think it is possible to know which seq in the file with 60 seq are note present in the file with 125 to know why is there a such issue?

Comment: @Benjamin Not sure if understand, do you think `a = df1[~df1['#qseqid'].isin(df2['seq2_id'])]` or `a = df2[~df2['seq2_id'].isin(df1['qseqid'])]` ?

Comment: ~ is for invert condition.

Comment: OK I see where is my error, I'm creating a new question to solve it thanks you :)